# Using if statements to test a score against a specific range of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I want to create a simple program that returns a statement if the student's test average score is between 40 and 50. Code is below:

```
first_test = int(input("Please enter your first test score: "))
second_test = int(input("Please enter your second test score: "))
third_test = int(input("Please enter your third test score: "))
average_score = (first_test + second_test + third_test) / 3
print(f"Your average score is: {average_score}")
if average_score >= 50:
    print("Well done!")
elif average_score < 50 and > 40
    print("Could be doing better")
else:
    print("You need to do better")
```

I tried using 'and ' and commas etc. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "a == x or y or z" always evaluate to True? How can I compare "a" to all of those?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true-how-can-i-compare-a-to-al)

Comment: `elif average_score < 50 and average_score > 40`

Comment: Or just `elif average_score > 40`. You don't need to check `< 50` because the first `if` statement precludes that.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the variable to the right side of the `and` as well, like this

```
first_test = int(input("Please enter your first test score: "))
second_test = int(input("Please enter your second test score: "))
third_test = int(input("Please enter your third test score: "))
average_score = (first_test + second_test + third_test) / 3
print(f"Your average score is: {average_score}")
if average_score >= 50:
    print("Well done!")
elif average_score < 50 and average_score > 40
    print("Could be doing better")
else:
    print("You need to do better")
```

Comment: I would add the fact that you can chain the expressions as `40 < average_score < 50` (ignoring the fact that `< 50` is redundant due to the first `if`).